# Python PYPM Install Problems

Tags: python, pypm

I'm trying to download modules using pypm and activestate.

PYPM is installing modules to `%APPDATA%\Python` on Windows. The activestate website says that if I want to install to `c:\python32`, it wont do it then "Unless the -g option is specified":

I have tried every combo in the terminal window. What does the `-g` command supposed to look like?

I have tried:

```
-g pypm install pycrypto
 pypm -g install pycrypto
 pypm  install -g pycrypto
 pypm  install  pycrypto -g
```

> Unless the `-g` option is specified, packages are not installed into
>   the ActivePython installation directory. Instead, PyPM follows the PEP
>   370 specification and installs packages by default in `~/.local` on
>   Unix and Mac and `%APPDATA%\Python` on Windows; and the Python
>   interpreter automatically picks up the local packages. To find where
>   the package was installed, use the show or files command.

What is the correct way? Is there an eaiser way to download modules (not manually)?

Answer (score 2):

Use pip tool:

```
pip install pycrypto
```